# What are the use of of square brackets in vba (access)

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm looking through an access database for work currently and came across some confusing code.

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
  Me.Parent!PF = Me.[Compound Number]
  Me.Parent.start = Me.[Study Start]
    'over and over for different variables
end sub
```

I'm wondering what the brackets are for in vba (outside of arrays)and why someone would need this code. Thanks

Comment: they let you use field names which would otherwise be a syntax error. e.g. consider `Me.Compound Number`. That's table "Me", with field "Compound", and some weird unknown/illegal garbage word "Number"

Comment: Access/VBA treats `spaces` as special characters, and special characters needs to be enclosed inside square brackets to be understood by the compiler that they are part of field/control name.

Answer (score 8):

Without the brackets you would have :

```
Me.Compound Number
```

Which would be a call to a routine called `Compound` with an argument called `Number`.

The square brackets escape the object name that contains a space (or other reserved characters, symbols or words).

Comment: Yup. It basically lets you use illegal identifier names, so you can call hidden members such as `MyCollection.[_NewEnum]`... it's **not** intended for bending the naming rules and having illegal identifier names all over the code.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon  Right!  I use it to hide certain members of custom enumerations following Chip Pearson's article here:  http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Enums.aspx.  Add a prefix to a member to hide it, which by itself is an illegal identifier.  Wrapping the name in square brackets makes it valid.